# Is it possible to create a Document Set using REST API

Tags: document-set, rest

I know this can be done using the JSOM, but is it possible via the REST API to create a document set?

Comment: Great question, Robert!

Comment: Thanks Vadim. I know it must be if the JSOM can do it. I'm hoping to be able to avoid using Fiddler or similar to figure it out. But it looks like I may have to.

Comment: So you had created document set using rest api?
I know its an old post but still curious to know the answer.
If not, have you tried to include property 'ContentTypeId':'DocumentSetId' in metadata while making ajax request? Maybe that work for you?

Comment: I've not tried yet. Going to use JSOM and see what it calls on the backend. Then I'll update this with an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### How to create a Document Set using SharePoint REST Interface

The following example demonstrates how to create a Document Set in SharePoint 2013:

```
function getListUrl(webUrl,listName,success, error) 
{
    var headers = {};
    $.ajax({       
       url: webUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/rootFolder?$select=ServerRelativeUrl",   
       type: "GET",   
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       },   
       success: function(data){
           success(data.d.ServerRelativeUrl);
       },
       error: error
    });
}

function createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderName,folderContentTypeId, success, error) 
{  
    getListUrl(webUrl,listName,
      function(listUrl) {
          var folderPayload = {
             'Title' : folderName,
             'Path' : listUrl
          };

          //Create Folder resource
          $.ajax({
                url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
                headers: {
                   "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                   "Slug": listUrl + "/" + folderName + "|" + folderContentTypeId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    success(data.d);
                },
                error: error
          });
      },
      error);
}


function createDocumentSet(webUrl,listName,folderName, success, error)
{
   createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderName,'0x0120D520', success, error);
}
```

Comments:

- `getListUrl` function is used for retrieving List/Library Url
- With some modifications applied (in fact it concerns `getListUrl` function only) it could be used in SharePoint 2010

**Example**

Create Document Set named `Orders` in `Documents` library:

```
createDocumentSet(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents','Orders',
  function(folder){
    console.log('Document Set ' + folder.Name + ' has been created succesfully'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to use this example to make a web service call from within a SharePoint Designer WorkFlow!! The "Slug" was a key factor!!!!  So happy...

Comment: Thanks, Vadim. Even though this uses `ListData.svc` and not `_API`, it was exactly what we needed.

Comment: It seems to ignore the folderPayload setting, is it possible at all to set metadata on creation?? I have a custom sitecolumn with a validation rule which causes an error on creation, if I remove the validation rule everything works fin.

Comment: @Vadim Does this still work?  When I run this code I get a 500 Internal Server error that just says "An error occurred while processing this request.

Comment: @James11, hm, it works for me, is Document Set content type is added into library?

Comment: @VadimGremyachev Are you using SharePoint Online? That's what I am using.  I was using a Custom content type based on the DocSet content type but I just tried adding the DocSet content type to my site and using the content type id for that but I still get the same error.

Comment: this works, but be careful for listnames with spaces in between them, in that case you might have to check the `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/` url