# Create a DocumentSet in host web using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest

I need to create a DocumentSet in the Hostweb from inside the App.

I have tried this:

```
    var info = {
        __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.DocumentSet' },
        AllowContentTypes: true,
        ContentTypesEnabled: true,
        ContentTypeID: '0x0120D520',
        Description: 'new documentset',
        Title: 'new documentset',
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(
            {
                'parameters': info
            }
        ),
        headers: {
            "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (site) {
         },
        error: function (error) {
        }
```

With no success, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

it does not seem possible to create Document Set using SharePoint 2013 REST API since SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create function is not accessible via REST. But you could utilize SharePoint 2010 REST API instead for that purpose.

[Is it possible to create a Document Set using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114882/is-it-possible-to-create-a-document-set-using-rest-api)