# Adding a folder to a list using the REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rest, folder

I have a GenericList that accepts folders as elements.

I know how to create those folders in Sharepoint's interface. I'd like to be able to generate them with a script, using the REST API.

I know how to create elements for a list using the REST API. Those elements have a 'folder' field, which is null for regular elements, or defer to the corresponding SP.Folder otherwise.

Basically, what kind of queries should I make so that the URL `http://sharepoint/_api/Web/Lists(guid'aa82af4c-f6cc-47fb-8fb3-adef934d9183')/Items(29)/Folder` stops answering me with 'null' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Vadim's answer here: [Is it possible to create a Document Set using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114882/is-it-possible-to-create-a-document-set-using-rest-api)

Instead of using (which is at the bottom of the first code snippet):

```
createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderName,'0x0120D520', success, error);
```

Use:

```
createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderName,'0x0120', success, error);
```

Comment: Thanks. It has a few issues though: it doesn't use the /api thingy, so... the fields actually use the language of the Sharepoint server (things like `Path` become `CheminDacces` for me... kinda sucks).

Answer (score 4):

According to [Working with folders and files with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Folders) the following example demonstrates how to **create** a Folder:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/folders
method: POST
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/document library relative url/folder name'}
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```

### JavaScript example (jQuery)

```
function createFolder(webUrl,folderUrl) {

    var folderPayload = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': folderUrl}; 

    return $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/web/folders",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
}
```

Usage

```
//create a folder named '2015' in Documents library
createFolder(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents/2015')
.done(function(data)
{
    var folder = data.d;
    console.log('Folder ' + folder.Name  + ' has been created successfully');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

### JavaScript example ([datajs](https://datajs.codeplex.com/))

The same example using [datajs library](https://datajs.codeplex.com/):

```
var folderPayload = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': 'Documents/2016'}; 
OData.request(
   { 
       requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/folders", 
       method: "POST", 
       headers: { "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), "DataServiceVersion": "3.0" },
       data: folderPayload 
   },
   function(folder)
   {
      console.log('Folder ' + folder.Name  + ' has been created successfully');    
   },
   function(error){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
```

Comment: My request is a bit different though. Just creating the folder isn't enough in the case of list sub-folders: the folders are created, but they don't show as a list entry. From @Jordan's answer, it's possible to create such sub-folders, but by using the /vti_bin interface instead of the /api interface (which brings in other problems, because the /vti_bin interface, for some reason, use translatable strings as field names... so you can't code a script that would work in all sharepoint installations).

Comment: is it possible to create an item within a folder in the list using REST API?

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricky way to get the folder of listitem. The FieldValueAsText node contains the FileRef field. The FileRef for a listitem is a odd string in the format
`/<sitecollection>/<web>/Lists/<listname>/<folder>/<id>_.000`.

To get the FileRef you have to expand the FieldValuesAsText. A select is strongly recommended. Otherwise you get all fields a second time in the FieldValuesAsText object.

```
_api/lists/getbyTitle('Title')/items?$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$select=Id,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef`
```

To get the folder you cant now use a little ugly string manipulation:

```
function getFolder(fileRef, listName) {
        // fileRef is in the format "/<sitecollection>/<web>/Lists/Infos/Bereiche/<id>_.000"
        var folderUrl = fileRef.substring((_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + listName + "/").length);
        var folderParts = folderUrl.split("/");
        folderParts.pop(); // Remove the <id>_.000 part
        return folderParts;
}
```

This function does not work for folders itself. Folders have an FileRef of `/<sitecollection>/<web>/Lists/<listname>/<folder>` (without the id part).

To exclude Folders from your result you have to add `$filter=FSObjType eq 0`. (Thats another odd thing with folders in REST, in the result this is called `FileSystemObjectType`, but if you filter it is `FSObjType`)