# Set Lookup Field while creating Document Set REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, document-set

I am creating document sets like described here: [Is it possible to create a Document Set using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114882/is-it-possible-to-create-a-document-set-using-rest-api)

(How) can I add metadata values (including lookup column value) to the payload? Or do I have to update metadata afterwards?

```
var folderContentTypeId = "0x0120D52000299C8B1D5E20484483DB25C6A80C045600B1166A451873EE40A22C2E455C11F9E2";
var folderName = companyTitle.trim();    
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var listName = "Kundenmappen";
var listUrl = webUrl + "/" + listName;
    
var folderPayload = {
        'Title' : companyTitle.trim(),
        'Path' : listUrl,
        };
            
        $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Slug": listUrl + "/" + folderName + "|" + folderContentTypeId
            },
     });
```

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I don't know for sure, but my guess is no, because this looks like you're creating the document set as a folder, which is a file system object, and list metadata is stored on the SP List Item that is associated with that file system object.  So you'd have to create the folder, then get the `folder.Item` and set the metadata on that.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @DylanCristy, yes that's probably correct and the way I did it. Thank you for replying.